# Remove the gap between a table heading and row

Tags: tables, spacing, tabularx, white-space

I want to remove the space between the languages and the proficiency levels. This was generated using a tabular component and I'm having trouble removing the large whitespace between the headings and the row contents. How can this be done?

[image]

This is the code used to generate this

```
% Document class and font size
\documentclass[a4paper,9pt]{extarticle}

% Packages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % For input encoding
\usepackage{geometry} % For page margins
\geometry{letterpaper, margin=0.75in} % Set paper size and margins
\usepackage{tabularx}

% Formatting
\setlist{noitemsep} % Removes item separation
\titleformat{\section}{\large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}[\titlerule] % Section title format
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{\baselineskip} 

\begin{document}

\section*{LANGUAGES}
\begin{center}
    \noindent
    \begin{tabular*}{0.95\textwidth}{
        @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
        l @{\ ---\ \extracolsep{0pt}} l @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
        l @{\ ---\ \extracolsep{0pt}} l @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
        l @{\ ---\ \extracolsep{0pt}} l
        @{}
        }
        \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\textbf{English} (Native)} &
        \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\textbf{French}} &
        \multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\textbf{Polish}} \\[2ex]
        Speaking & \textit{Fluent} & Speaking & \textit{Limited} & Speaking & \textit{Proficient} \\
        Listening & \textit{Fluent} & Listening & \textit{Limited} & Listening & \textit{Proficient} \\
        Reading & \textit{Fluent} & Reading & \textit{Proficient} & Reading & \textit{Limited} \\
        Writing &  \textit{Fluent} & Writing & \textit{Intermediate} & Writing & \textit{Basic} \\
    \end{tabular*}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  Are you talking about the `\\[2ex]` after `Polish`?  Have you tried just `\\ `?

Comment: Off-topic: You shouldn't specify `a4paper` as a document class level option if you're going to override it with the `geometry` package's option `letterpaper`.

Answer (score 0):

- To reduce the amount of whitespace between the title rule and the first row of the `tanular*` environment, set a smaller value for the fourth argument of `\titlespacing*`. In your code, this argument is `1\baselineskip`; I suggest you reduce it to `0.75\baselineskip`.
- To reduce the amount of whitespace between the first and second rows of the `tabular*` environment, change `\\[2ex]` to, say, `\\[0.5ex]`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[9pt]{extarticle} % no need for 'a4paper' option

\usepackage{iftex}
\ifpdftex
   %\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <-- new
\else
   \usepackage{fontspec}
\fi

\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{letterpaper, margin=0.75in} % paper size and margins

%\usepackage{tabularx} % not needed
\usepackage{array} % <-- new
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\itshape}l} % <-- automatic italics

%\usepackage{enumitem} % not needed
%\setlist{noitemsep}   % not needed

\usepackage{titlesec}  % <-- new
\titleformat{\section}{\large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}[\titlerule] 
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{1\baselineskip}{0.75\baselineskip} 

\begin{document}

\section*{LANGUAGES}

\begin{center}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % <-- new

\begin{tabular*}{0.95\textwidth}{% why not '1\textwidth'?
   @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
   l @{ --- \extracolsep{0pt}} L 
   @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
   l @{ --- \extracolsep{0pt}} L 
   @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
   l @{ --- \extracolsep{0pt}} L 
}
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{English} (Native)} &
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{French}} &
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Polish}} \\[0.5ex] % '2ex' is too much
Speaking & Fluent & Speaking & Limited & Speaking & Proficient \\
Listening & Fluent & Listening & Limited & Listening & Proficient \\
Reading & Fluent & Reading & Proficient & Reading & Limited \\
Writing & Fluent & Writing & Intermediate & Writing & Basic \\
\end{tabular*}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```